# WCF RESTful service - How do I make my service not need the xmlns attribute in a request?

Tags: c#, xml, rest, wcf

I am building a RESTful service that works when a request has the xmlns attribute in it. However, I need to make the service able to take request without the xmlns attribute.

This is what I have working now:

```
<ITEM_SEND xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WCFInventoryService">
  <TRAN_ID>9483564</TRAN_ID>
  <VENDOR_PART>D336</VENDOR_PART>
</ITEM_SEND>
```

This is what I need to accept as a request:

```
<ITEM_SEND>
  <TRAN_ID>9483564</TRAN_ID>
  <VENDOR_PART>D336</VENDOR_PART>
</ITEM_SEND>
```

Here is my interface:

```
namespace WCFInventoryService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    public interface IInvService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        //[WebGet(UriTemplate="/Employees",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml )]
        //Employee[] GetEmployees();
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
             UriTemplate = "")]
        ITEM_REPLY GetInventory(ITEM_SEND query);
    }

 public class ITEM_SEND
    {
        public string TRAN_ID { get; set; }
        public string VENDOR_PART { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've tried altering the namespace for the Data contract that I have for my request by setting it to "".

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class ITEM_SEND
    {
        public string TRAN_ID { get; set; }
        public string VENDOR_PART { get; set; }
    }
```

But that didn't work as when I view my svc in the browser my request changes from 
[image: Without Namespace = ""]

[image: With Namesspace = ""]

Comment: If you still have the option I'd switch to JSON. No namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly define your data contracts to not belong to any namespace-

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class ITEM_SEND
{
    [DataMember]
    public string TRAN_ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string VENDOR_PART { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: UGH! I actually saw this as a solution but it didn't work for me because I left off the DataMember annotations. I first thought this was not going to work but in staring at what you wrote I all of sudden saw that you added the [DataMember] annotations. Long story shot...It works!. Thax

Comment: Yes... If you decorate the class with [DataContract] then you have to explicitly mark the members you wish to expose with [DataMember]. Only these annotated  members are serialized to the request/response xml